# How to read in text file and parse it visibly as XML format using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a data file that comes from a client, and it is not parsed correctly how you would assume it to be for being human readable.  The tags in it are `<statement>` tags, and there are no line breaks. So it looks like the example below:

```
<statement><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2>...and so on until </statement>
<statement><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2>...and so on until </statement>
<statement><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2>...and so on until </statement>
```

Is there a quick way I can just parse this defining the root element, and re save the data file so it is parsed how you would assume to view an xml document such as the following:

```
<statement>
     <tag1></tag1>
     <tag2>
        <Tag2A></tag2A>
     </tag2>
</statement>
```

Thanks in advance. I am new to working with XML, and so learning the tools for it. Currently, I am reading the file in by lines `File.ReadLines`, and then looping through doing an XML `Parse()` like the following:

```
foreach (String item in lines)
{
    XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(item);
    sr.WriteLine(xElement.ToString().Trim());
}
```

This is taking over half of the processing time! Is there a quicker or better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading the lines as strings and them parsing them, it may be a better idea to parse the whole document at once, as an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) (assuming it's a valid XML document):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
foreach (var xElement in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    sr.WriteLine(xElement.ToString().Trim());
}
```

Or, if you want to include the root element's tags:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
sr.WriteLine(doc.Root);
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Except that I still get a Exception when writing "Out of memory". The file is too big. Like 256k @ 50+ statements.  The prior way I was doing was the IO process of writing in every foreach loop.  Just thought there would be a way to parse the document and re save it faster. I am seeing there really isn't so far.

Comment: Thank you though. This is te method and constructor I was looking for. I can start searching and reading some more from here, and figure out a solution when it comes to the memory issue.  Thanks again.